# MFC Menu Item remains grayed

Tags: mfc

I have a `CDialogEx` Class called Properties in which I handle the `ON_COMMAND` message. Now, `ON_COMMAND` should get called when I click the menu item `ID_EDIT_PROPERTIES` (as a submenu from main menu). The event handler wizard wrote that code for me, but when I start the Application the menu item remains grayed out. I've tried to manually activate it by calling `EnableMenuItem` when `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` happens, but to no avail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've found out that it gets handled if I target the Document class of my project. This is an easy workaround it seems. But I'm still curious why I cannot handle it from the CDialogEx class.

Comment: Does your `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler ever get called?

Comment: AFAIK, The command handler are not called for dialogs. (see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/242577)

Answer (score 2):

Per [`m_bAutoMenuEnable`](https://technet.microsoft.com/sr-latn-rs/library/dz33x6wb(v=vs.71)), When this data member is enabled (which is the default), menu items that do not have `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` or `ON_COMMAND` handlers will be automatically disabled when the user pulls down a menu.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to understand how menu items enabling/disabling is handled:

- If there is neither `ON_COMMAND` nor `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler the item is disabled.
- If there exists no `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler but there is an `ON_COMMAND` one in the currently active document or view (or even the "mainframe"), the item is enabled.
- If there exists a `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler, en-/disabling the item is determined by the handler (`pCmdUI->Enable(bEnableState)`).

Also keep in mind that:

- You may not call `EnableMenuItem()` yourself, instead call `pCmdUI->Enable(bEnableState)` in an `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` handler. This affects not only the menu item, but any other "command"-type item (with the same ID), eg main menu, context menu, toolbar or rebar button.
- Where to put the handler, is a matter of application design and depends on the data you are processing or representing. It can be put in the mainframe class (if it depends on some "global" data or setting), in the document class (if it depends on or changes some data or setting in the document - possibly affecting all views), or in the view class(-es) (depending on or affecting the current view only).

In your case, if I understand correctly, the item is disabled because the handler is in the `CDialogEx`-derived class, but no instance of this class has been created yet, ie there exists no `ON_COMMAND` handler for your  `ID_EDIT_PROPERTIES` command.

Comment: It has always been my understanding that, by design, a `CDialog` derived project does not have the nuts n bolts for using the `CCmdUI` approach. This is why I manually update menu item states myself on demand.

Answer (score 0):

I admit that I don't know if it is different for `CDialogEx`, But for `CDialog` I found that the `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` didn't ever work unless I handled the [`WM_KICKIDLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645422(v=vs.85).aspx) event.

In your `OnKickIdle` event handler make a call to:

[`CWnd::UpdateDialogControls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/49a832ee-bc34-4126-88b3-bc1d9974f6c4.aspx#cwnd__updatedialogcontrols)

There is a short **tutorial** on it [here](http://www.ucancode.net/Visual_C_Source_Code/WM_KICKIDLE-CCmdUI-ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI-WM_IDLEUPDATECMDUI-MFC-Example.htm).

Forgive me if `CDialogEx` supercedes this information and I will remove the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't really tried the UI update mechanism in `CDialog` or `CDialogEx` applications. If it doesn't work, it would be a pity, because it's one of MFC nicest features, not found in any other API I'm aware of, providing an excellent way to update command-items based on conditions, without having to write custom code and call it in EVERY action that could affect them. Nice if you found a way to re-enable it. Side note, an alternative to a Dialog-Based MFC app can be a SDI app without Doc/View architecture (it contains a View, which can be a `CFormView`, if you want controls on it).